# JavaFX + JAXB + ClassNotFoundException

Tags: xml, javafx, jaxb

Умоляю помочь, голову сломал, не понимаю, в чем дело.
Не компилится любой JavaFX проект, в котором используется javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.2 (пробовал разные версии).

Суть-то проблемы, как понимаю, проста: java-9 и ее модульность. 
Когда перетащил проект из 8 в 9 версию (из-за наличия нужной фичи), рабочий код в Intellij IDEA 2018.1 перестал запускаться. Но тут вылечилось просто: строчка --add-modules java.xml.bind в Run - Edit Configuration.

Но потом при попытке скомпилировать проект в JavaFX приложение оказалось, что библиотека JAXB ни при каких условиях не вписывается ни в JAR, ни в APP-файл (я под мак ОС, компилирую с включенной опцией Native bundle: all).

Причем, другие библиотеки компилируются вроде норм, по крайней мере, log4j точно вписался, потому что при запуске апликации успевает записать в отведенный ему лог инфу об ошибке. Вот, кстати, текст из лога:
https://pastebin.com/sG5mEUwC

Третий день рою интернет, читаю все советы – и ничего не помогает. 
Завел на соседнем компе (с другой версией макос) ИДЕЮ, скопировал туда весь проект, открыл, подцепил все зависимости, пробую скомпилировать – получаю то же самое. ((

Ссылку на проект привожу в конце, но вот специально, чтобы не мучать сообщество разбором моего г..кода, сделал отдельное простейшее приложение из одного окошка и двух классов. Один класс делает окошко и пишет другой класс в XML на диск. Затем сразу же читает обратно записанный XML, парсит его в объект, и выводит в окошко в лейбл значения полученных полей прочитанного класса. 
То есть это простейший учебнейший пример чтения / записи XML с помощью JAXB.

И вот эта примитивнейшая поделка точно так же никак не генерится в работающее приложение!!

Вот ссылка на эту мелкую поделку:
https://github.com/swen922/TryToDeploy
Приложение компилится, но виснет при запуске, видимо, при вылете эксепшна. Логгера в нем нет, так что точнее сказать не могу.

При этом сделал для проверки еще 2 других проекта с копией этой поделки, но с небольшими изменениями: 
- JSON вместо JAXB
- и вообще без сторонних библиотек
И оба проекта, в отличие от первого, компилят работающие APP.

Очень прошу уважаемых знатоков хоть что-то посоветовать дельное, проект встрял в самом конце, полгода работы в никуда.. 
Или заменять сериализацию на тот же JSON, но у него текст неудобно читать, XML можно при необходимости прочесть все же.. Да и пишет JAXB удобнее – прямо в файл и из файла.

На всякий случай вот скриншот из структуры мелкого проекта / Libraries:
[image: скриншот jaxb импорта]

а также на всякий случай вот ссылка на большой проект, но в нем все происходит точно так же, как в мелком:
https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountFXProbe2

Да, еще: все проекты – НЕ Мавен. В мавен даже соваться боюсь с этим JAXB (к тому же пока и не выучил еще его)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге тупо накидал в папку src в проекте все джарики из JAXB, которые оно не хотело включать в компилируемый app — и заработало. 
Грязное решение, лучше, конечно все в classpath прописать, как положено, но для запуска приложения хватило  ))